# How to map pages pinned by get_user_pages_fast to use them as a virtually continuous buffer in the driver?

Tags: linux, mapping, driver

I'm writing a Linux kernel driver that provides asynchronous communication for the user space application. The implementation works as follows:

- The application delivers the address of the buffer to receive data via `ioctl`
- The driver uses `get_user_pages_fast` to ensure the kernel access to the output buffer, the `vmap` is used to create the virtual memory area to access the buffer in the kernel
- The driver is filled with received data in the interrupts
- After all the data are received, the kernel removes the mapping (with `vunmap`) and puts the user pages back, finally it notifies the application about availability of the data.

Below are the essential parts of the code (extracted from my driver and simplified):

```
struct page ** pages = NULL;
long pinned = 0;
int i;
void * vbuf = NULL;
void * vresp = NULL;

if (!access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, buffer, max_data_length)) {
   pr_alert("wrong access");
   res = -EFAULT;
   goto error1;
}
const unsigned long offset = ((unsigned long) buffer) & (PAGE_SIZE-1);
    int nr_pages = DIV_ROUND_UP(offset + max_data_length, PAGE_SIZE);
pages = (struct page **) kzalloc(sizeof(struct page)*nr_pages, GFP_KERNEL);
if(!pages) {
    pr_alert("can't alloc pages");
    res = -EFAULT;
    goto1;
}
pinned = get_user_pages_fast(((unsigned long) buffer ) & PAGE_MASK,nr_pages,1,pages);
if(pinned != nr_pages) {
    for(i=0; i<pinned; i++) {
        put_page(pages[i]);
    }
    kfree(pages);
    pr_alert("can't pin pages");
    res = -EFAULT;
    goto error1;
}
vbuf = vmap(pages,nr_pages,VM_MAP, pgprot_writecombine(PAGE_KERNEL));
vresp = vbuf + offset;
if(!vbuf) {
    pr_alert("can't vmap pages");
    res = -EFAULT;
    goto error1;
}
```

After the above code is executed, the vresp pointer is used to store the received data. After the transmission, pages are freed with:

```
int i;
vunmap(vbuf);
for(i=0; i < nr_pages; i++) {
   set_page_dirty(pages[i]);
   put_page(pages[i]);
}
kfree(pages);
```

The original code was working in a few architectures, but fails on multicore ARM machine. It looks like data written to the buffer pointed by `vresp` are not visible in the `buffer` in the user space application. I have added control prints in the code and verified that the addresses are correct. Is the usage of vmap to create continuous mapping for pages delivered by `get_user_pages_fast` correct?
Maybe I should use other flag than `VM_MAP` or other protection than  `pgprot_writecombine(PAGE_KERNEL)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I have found the answer. Indeed the problem is related to the `prot` argument in the `vmap` function. It should be set to `PAGE_KERNEL` instead of `pgprot_writecombine(PAGE_KERNEL))`.
In the user space application this memory is accessed via cache, so if I created the mapping with cache partially disabled via pgprot_writecombine, it resulted in inconsistent access to the memory.
I have modified the mapping line to:

```
vbuf = vmap(pages,nr_pages,VM_MAP,PAGE_KERNEL);
```

and the code works correctly even on multiprocessor ARM.